# Typescript import of an ES5 anonymous function

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am working with ES6 import syntax and importing a 3rd party ES5 module who exports a single export which is an unnamed function:

```
module.exports = function (phrase, inject, callback) { ... }
```

Because there is no default export but rather a single anonymous function output I must import and use like so:

```
import * as sentiment from 'sentiment';
const analysis = sentiment(content);
```

This gives the Typescript error:

> error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'typeof "sentiment"' has no compatible call signatures.

And I suppose I'm getting that because i'm not typing the ES5 import correctly (there is no public typings file). Back when I though the function was a *default export* I had the following definition:

```
interface IResults {
  Score: number;
  Comparitive: number;
}

declare var fn: (contents: string, overRide?: IDictionary<number>) => IResults;

declare module "sentiment" {
  export default fn;
};
```

This all made perfect sense but seeing as the import is **not** a default export I'm not sure how to define this module and function. I did try the following:

```
declare module "sentiment" {
  export function (contents: string, overRide?: IDictionary<number>): IResults;
};
```

and while this seems is a valid export definition it does not match the anonymous call definition and throws the following error:

> error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'typeof "sentiment"' has no compatible call signatures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to import this way in this case.
As it states in the [Modules: export = and import = require()](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require):

> When importing a module using export =, TypeScript-specific import let
>   = require("module") must be used to import the module.

So you'll have to do this:

```
import sentiment = require("sentiment");
const analysis = sentiment(content);
```

The definition file should probably look like:

```
declare function fn(contents: string, overRide?: IDictionary<number>): IResults;
export = fn;
```